# Sublime Text 2 Tab Auto-Complete

Tags: sublimetext2

I have mostly worked in Adobe Dreamweaver (don't hate too much, I really like some of its feature that I'm about to mention). I'd really like to become proficient in Sublime Text 2. There are two things I'm looking to figure out:

1. When I start typing a tag and it auto suggests what it thinks I'm typing, I can hit tab or enter to auto-complete the tag. But when I do this, it makes the closing tag too. I hate this, because I go back to change things often, then when I tab to auto complete, it adds in the entire closing tag. So my question is can I make it ONLY auto-complete the opening tag when I hit tab or enter? (btw, I have emmet installed too)
2. My next question, if anyone is familiar with Dreamweaver, whenever I open an HTML file, it opens all corresponding files in a sub menu below the tab. So I open say, index.html, and below it appears, automatically, my css file, js file, and any files that I've put in the html file. With Sublime Text, I have to go to the trouble to open all those files with it. Is there any plugin or way to make Sublime replicate this?

Thanks so much for any help anyone can provide!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is a bit old, and maybe you've discovered the answer, but for #1, you can set the "auto_complete_commit_on_tab" setting to true in your user settings.

http://www.sublimetext.com/docs/2/auto_complete.html

Comment: Thank you very much! It's the little things that matter and this worked.

Comment: @Andrew Hey can you tell me what do i need to do if my autocompletion doesn't work,its going to the new line on hitting enter instead of completion. can you help ?

Comment: @Abhinay do you have auto_complete_commit_on_tab set to true? If so, I think enter becomes only a new-line.

Comment: @Andrew Yeah,I figured it out after asking you, but thanks for help.I saw my theme was actually overriding this command and setting it to auto_complete_commit_on_tab true.Still your solution works for me indirectly. thanks.